# PHP detecting human browser in cron job

Tags: php, user-agent

I want to prevent users from running my cron job manually.  Apart from using an unpredictable filename I want to have some sort of check in code.

Obviously using any clientside headers is a waste of time so I thought the easiest way around this would be to detect the presence of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` which as far as I know is not set in CLI.

Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: which method did you use?  Any good results?

Comment: I used php_sapi_name() ... seems the most robust to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [`php_sapi_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php). It returns the type of interface between web server and PHP.

Example:

```
<?php

if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
  // CLI
}
else {
  // HTTP
}
```

For more information, and additional examples, have a look at http://www.electrictoolbox.com/determine-php-run-via-http-or-cli/.

Answer (score 3):

in your .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

order allow deny
deny from all
allow from YOUR SERVER IP ADDRESS ONLY
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for IP address, if its local, or server ip then run it, otherwise return.

```
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

Answer (score 2):

My cron jobs are in a folder that is password protected using [htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/es/howto/auth.html). You can set an easy password and be sure nobody will lose his time trying to access it. I don't use any IP-based techniques because this is a server dependency I don't want to have.